# check for UTC and LOT timezone values of date and time when insert or Update into mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How to adjust `LOT` and `UTC` time when we enter input from user and select LOT or UTC Timezone. I have one form which has a `date` entry field and `time` entry field. also radio buttons`for selection of LOT or UTS and dropdown for select Timezone value some are pasted here see,`(GMT -12:00) Eniwetok, Kwajalein (GMT -11:00) Midway Island, Samoa, (GMT +5:30) Bombay, Calcutta, Madras, New Delhi etc..` so I want to check that Enter the date and time with selected UTC and also adjust the time when we insert into the table. I. g If just thinks I am currently In London city and I have filled up form. I enter date 2015-02-02 Time 10:00:05 and I select Time Zone UTC then when it insert in mysql database time and date adjust related Timezone or check with UTC or LOT.

Comment: Can any one please help

Comment: If any one did n't get my question then please tell me I will explain what i exactly want